# Indexed view - SUM function that references a nullable expression

Tags: sql-server

I have table with time entries with following columns:

- Id (PK)
- Date
- EmployeeId
- State (state of the entry New, Approved, etc.)
- Quantity

And I would like to create an indexed view which groups time entries by day and employee. So I used:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Test1
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
  SELECT 
    Date, EmployeeId, SUM(Quantity), SUM(CASE State = 1 THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END) AS QuantityApproved 
  FROM 
    TimeEntries 
  GROUP BY 
    EmployeeId, Date

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1   
    ON dbo.Test1 (EmployeeId, Date);  
GO
```

But when I try to make it an indexed view an error occurs:

```
Cannot create the clustered index "IDX_V1" on view "dbo.Test1" because the view references an unknown value (SUM aggregate of nullable expression). Consider referencing only non-nullable values in SUM. ISNULL() may be useful for this.
```

Obviously using ISNULL would help in case of QuantityApproved column. But this is not a solution for me as 0 may also indicate there are 2 records (Quantity=-1 and QUantity=1) on the same day.

Also I can use an auxiliary column for ABS value for this case, but having NULL there is very convenvient as I do not need to solve anything else.

Is there any other way to overcome this?

Comment: You can use ISNULL inside the sum and place a 0 when it is NULL. Quantity =-1 and Quantity =1 will give you 0 not null.
SUM(CASE State = 1 THEN ISNULL(Quantity,0) ELSE NULL END)

Comment: @Arkadiusz I need it to be NULL and not 0 if there is Quantity=-1 and QUantity=1, otherwise it is not possible for me to distinguish these two cases.

Comment: Add count similar to your sum with the CASE, so when QuantityApproved = 0 and countApproved=0 it's null, if countApproved > 0 this means Quantity =-1 and Quantity =1

Comment: @sepupic thanks, that's what I was affraid of :) ... in fact it means duplicating all columns (these I noted were just example ones, there's many such columns); so no other trick?

Comment: Can you use any other value (not 0) in your isnull function? Maybe smth like -999999999? This is for distinguish from 0 when you have Quantity and -Quantity

Comment: @sepupic this came to my mind too. but the problem is that i cannot use ISNULL over entire SUM (error occurs) and at the individial row level it wont work fine, because some entries might be in given state - are added to sum, but others not -99999 is added to sum and the result does not give any sense then